# add the name of the author cited in my paper

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using `ieeeconf` package for writing my paper. The references are output just as number like [1]. What I need is to get the name of the author like bib and al. [1].

my code is:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{c1} bib....
\end{thebibliography}
```